# PowerPoint: Can't open PP 95 files in PP 2003

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I received the following error when trying to open a presentation in PP 2003:

> You are attempting to open a file type
>   that is blocked by your registry
>   policy setting.

Comment: I have every intent on answering this myself in case of the statistically unlikely event that someone else has this problem...

Comment: i like the way you state your intent - you do realize that the world has 6 billion people, and over a billion PC users right? "Statistically unlikely"? 5.5 million results on Google for this "statistically unlikely" event.

Comment: I was amazed we still had files around that hadn't been edited in at least 10 years *and* were still necessary.  With the frequency of getting new machines in the late 90s/early 2000s, it's amazing they made it through untouched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the registry scripts from [KB 938810](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/938810).  There is a restore script when you've completed your PP95 conversion.